# htmlspecialchars - there must be a better way

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

My understanding is that all variables should be output through htmlspecialchars() in a view.

Are there any approaches or methods to do this, without having to specify the function on each appropriate line in each view?

The best that I could come up with is to have a helper function as follows:
function html_escape($var)

```
function h($var)
{
  if (is_array($var))
  {
    return array_map('h', $var);
  }
  else
  {
    return htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF8');
  }
}
```

But still...this could get very tedious!

Any ideas?

Comment: who says htmlspecialchars should be used for every variable output?

Comment: This is one the reasons why PHP templating engines exist. Check [this tutorial](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/17/getting-started-with-php-templating/) for some info.

Comment: @imm Well, I mean to say for every user-provided variable

Comment: @Michael Mior - Thanks - nice article!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have the function `h()` output the escaped data, rather than return it. Therefore, instead of writing `<?php echo h($myvar); ?>` you may write `<?php h($myvar); ?>`. This is now two characters shorter than echoing the variable without converting to entities.

Answer (score 1):

It's an important distinction to note that not *all variables* must be run through htmlentities/htmlspecialchars, just ones that contain user-supplied content in anyway, that are not already filtered against a rule-set to prevent arbitrary code inclusion.

You could create a helper function to cut down on the typing slightly, or loop all user-supplied input through htmlentities/htmlspecialchars in your controllers before handing them off to the view (though, this will likely be less efficient since it is unlikely every piece of user-supplied input will be displayed)

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is probably the closest you come to an easy escape in allot of situations.

Personally i use a little loop on my variables, if i know i'm going to be using any `$_GET` variables in my html output, i run this:

```
<?php
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
  $_GET[$key] = htmlspecialchars($value);
}
?>
```

Then start my html tags right after.

Not everything needs to be escaped though, unless the user have any influence on it.

In addition, you could have a script called `escape.php`, which uses the above method on common variables you use, like $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE and so on, then `include('escape.php')` it in your scripts before use in the html output.

All over it pretty much depends on your taste and what you need for your project.